# Angular observable pipe return array

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable, angular9

I'm fairly new to Angular 9, and essentially I am wondering how do I return an array of objects from an async source? I currently have a firestore query in which the documents that are returned have a reference whose data I wish to render.

**ngOnInit**

```
this.currentUserRef.collection('links', ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)).get()
            .pipe(map(querySnap => {
                const ret = [];
                querySnap.forEach(doc => {
                    const val = doc.get('otherUser').get().then(userData => {return userData});
                    ret.push(val);
                });
                return ret;
            })).subscribe(val => {
                this.links = val;
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let link of links | async">
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <img [src]="getImage(link.get('profilepic'))">
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
                <h2>{{link.get('name')}}</h2>
                <p>{{link.get('bio')}}</p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox id="{{link.id}}"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
```

This currently returns the error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Promise]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
And when I remove the async pipe in the HTML it returns a zoneawarepromise.

## EDIT

```
this.links = this.currentUserRef.collection('links', ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)).get()
            .pipe(map(querySnap => {
                const ret = [];
                querySnap.forEach(async doc => {
                    const val = await doc.get('otherUser').get().then(userData => {return userData});
                    ret.push(val);
                });
                return ret;
            }));
```

This now works however I don't know how efficient and scalable the solution is for a large number of documents due to the
`ret` array
Note: querySnap is an object that has a built-in forEach method to loop through the array in it's `docs` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not advisable to mix promises and observables. They do play well together, but it jumbles and confuses your code. It's also very simple to convert a promise into an observable. Most operators that create/deal with higher-order observables will do the conversion for you. Otherwise, `from(promise)` returns an observable as well.

#### Using forkJoin

In this case, `forkJoin` accepts an array of `Promise` without complaint.

`forkJoin` will run all the promises concurrently and return an array of responses once/if they all complete/resolve.

```js
this.links = this.currentUserRef.collection(
  'links', 
  ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)
).get().pipe(
  mergeMap(querySnap => forkJoin(
    querySnap.docs.map(
      doc => doc.get('otherUser').get()
    ))
  )
);
```

#### Using concat

`concat` can also accept promises as parameters. We use the spread operator (...) to turn an array into a list of parameters.

This is actually closer to what you achieve with promises, as you `await` each promise before running the next one. This will run your promises one at a time (and not concurrently, the way `forkJoin` does

```js
this.links = this.currentUserRef.collection(
  'links', 
  ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)
).get().pipe(
  mergeMap(querySnap => concat(
    ...querySnap.docs.map(
      doc => doc.get('otherUser').get()
    ))
  ),
  toArray()
);
```

#### Aside: Cleaning up your promise code

This:

```js
this.links = this.currentUserRef.collection('links', ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)).get()
            .pipe(map(querySnap => {
                const ret = [];
                querySnap.forEach(async doc => {
                    const val = await doc.get('otherUser').get().then(userData => {return userData});
                    ret.push(val);
                });
                return ret;
            }));
```

is equivalent to

```js
this.links = this.currentUserRef.collection(
  'links', 
  ref => ref.where('pendingRequest', '==', false)
).get().pipe(
  map(querySnap => {
    const ret = [];
    querySnap.forEach(async doc => 
      ret.push(await doc.get('otherUser').get())
    );
    return ret;
  })
)
```

Basically, if you're using await, you don't need `.then(...`

Comment: I can't exactly test this with your code. What's your error?

Comment: So querySnap is an object that contains an array called docs which I applied the map function to and from the get('otherUser').get() I returned the custom object that contains the data I need to render. Not only is it not rendering but I am getting an error saying "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." when I try to render it in the HTML

Comment: That's a problem with your question perhaps? In your edit above, (The one you say works) querySnap is an array and not an object. - Also, it looks like this.links is undefined. Are you using angular's callbacks correctly? (NgOnit and such?). I'm at a loss as to why that would work for your above though

Comment: My apologies, querySnap has a built-in method called forEach() which loops through the array embedded in the object. That could be used or you could extract the docs array in the object and use traditional array looping methods. As for angular's callbacks, I am only using ngOninit currently and the code inside is the one I mentioned in my question with your fixes patched on.

Comment: "That could be used or you could extract the docs array in the object and use traditional array looping methods." - Try that? The code I wrote above works well for me. I've changed it to use querySnap.docs.map. See if that helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226950/discussion-between-sree-grandhe-and-mrk-sef).

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
            .pipe(map(querySnap => {
                const ret = [];
                querySnap.forEach(doc => {
                    const val = doc.get('otherUser').get().then(userData => {return userData});
                    ret.push(val);
                });
                return ret;
            })).map(val => {
                this.links = of(val);
        });
```

basically you new to add an observable stream to links variable.